# Storing Multiple Features of FeatureCollection in PostGIS geography field

Tags: postgis, features

I am working on GO Echo project and we connect to a PostgreSQL database running PostGIS.

I am getting the following json into my rest api

```
  {
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     -122.47812398582933,
                     37.79327313211862
                  ],
                  [
                     -122.45659724682807,
                     37.79251379803499
                  ],
                  [
                     -122.47566171795367,
                     37.78461000754145
                  ],
                  [
                     -122.47812398582933,
                     37.79327313211862
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         },
         "properties":null
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     -122.435644500556,
                     37.78945677677799
                  ],
                  [
                     -122.40663372785089,
                     37.786988387557116
                  ],
                  [
                     -122.4258779069805,
                     37.779960074721366
                  ],
                  [
                     -122.435644500556,
                     37.78945677677799
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         },
         "properties":null
      }
   ]
}
```

If I try to store 1 feature in the db as follows - it works fine

```
gj, err := area.GeoJSON.Features[0].Geometry.MarshalJSON()
    query := sq.
        Insert("areas").
        Columns("id", "geog").
        Values(sq.Expr("DEFAULT"), sq.Expr("ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(?),4326)", string(gj))).
        Suffix("RETURNING id").
        RunWith(dbCxn).
        PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)

    query.QueryRow().Scan(
        &area.ID,
    )
```

However I am struggling to find a way to store all the features when more than 1 feature is submitted in the request.
I tried changing gj to this line but that will not save

```
gj, err := area.GeoJSON.MarshalJSON()
```

What is the correct approach to follow here?

Comment: You are accessing `Features[0]`. Use a loop over this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted

I used the following code to iterate to iterate over the features passed in, added them to a slice and used the geojson methond NewMultiPolygonFeature to create a MultiPolygon

```
var multiPolygon = make([][][][]float64, 0)
for _, elem := range area.GeoJSON.Features {

    // Iterate over the geometries and ensure they are all polygons
    if (!elem.Geometry.IsPolygon()) {
        glog.Info("Supplied area is not a polygon. It is of type ",elem.Geometry.Type)
        return nil, nil
    }
    multiPolygon = append(multiPolygon, elem.Geometry.Polygon)
}
    gj, err := geojson.NewMultiPolygonFeature(multiPolygon...).Geometry.MarshalJSON()
gj, err := area.GeoJSON.Features[0].Geometry.MarshalJSON()
    query := sq.
        Insert("areas").
        Columns("id", "geog").
        Values(sq.Expr("DEFAULT"), sq.Expr("ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(?),4326)", string(gj))).
        Suffix("RETURNING id").
        RunWith(dbCxn).
        PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)

    query.QueryRow().Scan(
        &area.ID,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with a code (that works for you) but you could try to iterate first command:

area.GeoJSON.Features[0].Geometry.MarshalJSON() to area.GeoJSON.Features[i].Geometry.MarshalJSON()

I am assuming that first polygon is successfully inserted in db.

Comment: Yes the first polygon will get inserted. Do you think this is possible to store all the polygons in the same row in the 1 field? LIke is there a way to combine them into 1 geography field?

Comment: You can do that in case that feature is MultiPolygon, otherwise, I would advise you to insert new polygon as a new row.

Comment: OK makes sense - would you be able to point me at any examples of this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with GO - sorry

Comment: If you had a sample of this in java or any programming language it would be a great help.

Comment: In my use cases, I always stored data locally and then import to database as a file. You can use logic from here (I am not the creator of this): https://gist.github.com/bdw/6362152b96c30dbe247b46f1cd15ee0f